Fedora Workstation does not suspend on HP Envy x360 Laptop (2018)
I have an older, but not old, 2018 laptop as indicated in the question, which for the life of me I cannot get to suspend with any of: Fedora Workstation; Atomic Desktops Silverblue, Kinoite, Budgie; the Fedora KDE Desktop Spin; nor Ubuntu Desktop. It does suspend/resume flawlessly with Fedora Atomic Sway Desktop, and Windows 10. All with the latest versions downloaded yesterday and today, including all updates, installing onto a newly partitioned drive.
The visible symptom is that the display goes black, and the system appears to freeze; no disk activity; no change after several minutes of waiting; power light remains on; keyboard backlight remains on. The only recourse is to force power off and reboot.
One thing I have noticed with all the failing Linux distros is that they output a message at the beginning of booting saying "call_irq_handler: 0.110 No IRQ handler for vector", though I can find no entry in any logs, neither dmesg or the Logs GUI app, that references that. I mention that only because the Sway Atomic Desktop did not. It may be a complete red herring.
I am relatively new(ish) to Linux, but know how to fiddle-fuddle my way to resolving most issues with a combination of decades of experience on computers of all stripes and searching the internet. But this one has me foxed. Clearly the computer can reliably suspend/resume, but something about Linux does not want to sleep. The big obstacle is that I don't really know where to look for information on this level of problem with Linux.
Any help would be very much appreciated!
System Info
dmidecode -t bios:
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.0.0 present.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 24 bytes
BIOS Information
    Vendor: AMI
    Version: F.24
    Release Date: 03/16/2022
    Address: 0xF0000
    Runtime Size: 64 kB
    ROM Size: 16 MB
    Characteristics:
        PCI is supported
        BIOS is upgradeable
        BIOS shadowing is allowed
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        EDD is supported
        5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
        8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
        Serial services are supported (int 14h)
        Printer services are supported (int 17h)
        ACPI is supported
        USB legacy is supported
        Smart battery is supported
        BIOS boot specification is supported
        Function key-initiated network boot is supported
        Targeted content distribution is supported
        UEFI is supported
    BIOS Revision: 15.24
    Firmware Revision: 63.18

dmidecode -t system:
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.0.0 present.

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: HP
    Product Name: HP ENVY x360 Convertible 15-bq1xx
    Version:  
    Serial Number: 8CG802052W
    UUID: 4409c9d8-f508-11e7-9a05-2c6fc94442fa
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: 1ZA02AV
    Family: 103C_5335KV HP Envy

Handle 0x000E, DMI type 32, 20 bytes
System Boot Information
    Status: No errors detected

lscpu:
Architecture:             x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):         32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:          43 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:             Little Endian
CPU(s):                   8
  On-line CPU(s) list:    0-7
Vendor ID:                AuthenticAMD
  BIOS Vendor ID:         Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Model name:             AMD Ryzen 5 2500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx
    BIOS Model name:      AMD Ryzen 5 2500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx   Unknown CPU @ 2.0GHz
    BIOS CPU family:      107
    CPU family:           23
    Model:                17
    Thread(s) per core:   2
    Core(s) per socket:   4
    Socket(s):            1
    Stepping:             0
    Frequency boost:      enabled
    CPU(s) scaling MHz:   89%
    CPU max MHz:          2000.0000
    CPU min MHz:          1600.0000
    BogoMIPS:             3992.26
    Flags:                fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflus
                          h mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_t
                          sc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf rapl pni pclmulqdq m
                          onitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lah
                          f_lm cmp_legacy extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw sk
                          init wdt tce topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_llc mwaitx cpb hw_p
                          state ssbd ibpb vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 rdseed adx smap clflushop
                          t sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 clzero irperf xsaveerptr arat npt lbrv svm_lo
                          ck nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthre
                          shold avic v_vmsave_vmload vgif overflow_recov succor smca sev sev_es
Caches (sum of all):      
  L1d:                    128 KiB (4 instances)
  L1i:                    256 KiB (4 instances)
  L2:                     2 MiB (4 instances)
  L3:                     4 MiB (1 instance)
NUMA:                     
  NUMA node(s):           1
  NUMA node0 CPU(s):      0-7
Vulnerabilities:          
  Gather data sampling:   Not affected
  Itlb multihit:          Not affected
  L1tf:                   Not affected
  Mds:                    Not affected
  Meltdown:               Not affected
  Mmio stale data:        Not affected
  Reg file data sampling: Not affected
  Retbleed:               Mitigation; untrained return thunk; SMT vulnerable
  Spec rstack overflow:   Mitigation; Safe RET
  Spec store bypass:      Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl
  Spectre v1:             Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
  Spectre v2:             Mitigation; Retpolines; IBPB conditional; STIBP disabled; RSB filling; PBRSB-e
                          IBRS Not affected; BHI Not affected
  Srbds:                  Not affected
  Tsx async abort:        Not affected

lsblk:
NAME                                          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
sda                                             8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
└─sda1                                          8:1    0 931.5G  0 part  
  └─luks-de452dcc-6950-418d-96ea-dc98f511accc 253:2    0 931.5G  0 crypt /home
zram0                                         252:0    0     8G  0 disk  [SWAP]
nvme0n1                                       259:0    0 476.9G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1                                   259:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2                                   259:2    0     1G  0 part  /boot
├─nvme0n1p3                                   259:3    0    32G  0 part  
│ └─luks-95e4413b-1083-46f3-8e80-fee9278cddef 253:1    0    32G  0 crypt [SWAP]
└─nvme0n1p4                                   259:4    0 443.4G  0 part  
  └─luks-358e1cf7-3186-49be-89cb-b18b7f353d0c 253:0    0 443.4G  0 crypt /

lsusb:
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:58e6 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. HP Wide Vision FHD Camera
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0483:91d1 STMicroelectronics Sensor Hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bda:b00b Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Realtek Bluetooth 4.2 Adapter
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

lspci:
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 PCIe GPP Bridge [6:0]
00:01.6 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 PCIe GPP Bridge [6:0]
00:01.7 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 PCIe GPP Bridge [6:0]
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus A
00:08.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 61)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 7
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Intel Corporation SSD 660P Series (rev 03)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven Ridge [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] (rev c4)
04:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio Controller
04:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
04:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven USB 3.1
04:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven USB 3.1
04:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller
05:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 51)

